# One Plus Device Issue while sending the SMS

Tags: android, arrays

One Plus device Issue getting the Exception when trying the Sending SMS in grammatically getting the Exception Java.lang.Security Exception .

```
            try {
                String message=selectedContactsMap.get(mobileNumber);

/*                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(mobileNumber,null, message,
                        null, null);*/

                SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
                ArrayList<String> parts =sm.divideMessage(message);
                int numParts = parts.size();

                ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
                    sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0));
                    deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0));
                }

                sm.sendMultipartTextMessage(mobileNumber,null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Birthday.this,"Send Message Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 1000);



            } catch (Exception e) {

//                    Toast.makeText(Birthday.this,"Something went 
 // wrong.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(Birthday.this,"Error:- 
   "+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();`enter code here`
                progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
```

All device is working the fine Only Problem is One Plus Device

Comment: can you post value of SMS_SENT,SMS_DELIVERED

Comment: add following permission as well, i guess from SmsManager internally check phone state before sending sms. this is just based on blogs i read and tried on my one plus 6 and it worked try your luck with same <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: Already add the Both permission Like Send SMS and Read Phone State still is not working..

Comment: have you granted both permission from settings or runtime

Comment: I am asking the Permission run  time and settings  both will be granted but all device is working fine getting the problem send the SMS in programmatic throw the exception java .lang.Security exception   .

Comment: i have no clue than i encountered same problem bt that fixed with permission addition